# Vs Code debugging of mean stack app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, debugging

I want to debug a mean app in vs code. Like we debug a ASP.NET app in visual studio. I follow the debugging process in documentation but when i send request from angular.js app, debugger won't capture that request. So kindly help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Follow given links to catch up node.js debugging in VS Code

https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging